# Why is it wrong to use InstanceType on generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why is it wrong to use `InstanceType` on generics? Whether it's covariant or contravariant？

```
interface Ctor {
  new(): Instance;
}

interface Instance {
  print(): void;
}

function f1<T extends Ctor>(ctor: T) {
  // Error: Type 'Instance' is not assignable to Type 'InstanceType<T>'
  const ins: InstanceType<T> = new ctor();
  ins.print();
}

function f2(ctor: Ctor) {
  // No error
  const ins: InstanceType<Ctor> = new ctor();
  ins.print();
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJgPZWQbwFDLIgQDuAFAJQBcyAkiAM5hwhIDceAvnnqJLIhT0mLJLgLIADlD6UaANwzAAJh254YAV1ZhgGEMhgBGADwAVZBAAekEMoZpMUAHxkETmmYrjCAel-IAKJQUFieAJ6SKADkwsysENHIwA4gGGDIcAwMwADmIHAARgA2KJjIZpExcaIQlVHmztESCPpMyYw0NQn1EI3IALxEpMjuWJQchKAMAHTSshRqPFo6egYwAExuHo5Y3vh+AQByGJYhWC1tGdNdjPFIvSboWM6DwySjThMS03My4N9uEA)

Comment: This is a really interesting question!  It's rare that there's a TS question that stumps me but I am stumped.

Comment: This doesn't shed any light on the issue, but the same can be observed with function types and `ReturnType<T>` instead of constructor signatures. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQEo0D4oBKEwAagIYA2AUFQJYLAQBOAZmUtEaZVAN5VQoYJvWDYAXFABuAe1oATANxUAvjRaIkwWjIRQWARgA8AFSgQAHowTyAzrE24MG5JJM5+gpLtvAoTYnIKSS44JgQTcAhTfHQXJGxlQQDuCgA6YVFE1XVNbV19ACZnTUl4ZA8BKG8EX39AyhDiMIioo3KkWP1NbOSG9MyGbLUgA)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think is the problem: Typescript determines the compile-time type of the expression `new ctor()` by looking at the type of `ctor` (which is `T`), checking that `T` must have a constructor signature (it does), and then finding what the constructor signature of `T` returns. But `T` could be any subtype of `Ctor`, so its constructor signature could return any subtype of `Instance`.

There are two reasonable things a compiler could do in this case:

- Either invent a new type variable (let's call it `R extends Instance`) and let the type of the expression `new ctor()` be `R`,
- or just let the type of the expression be `Instance`.

Typescript does the latter, perhaps because Typescript only creates type variables if you tell it to; it never does so implicitly. This gives the expression a weaker type than necessary for the assignment to `InstanceType<T>` to typecheck, because `InstanceType<T>` *does* explicitly create a type variable `R` (using an `infer` clause in a conditional type), which may be an arbitrary subtype of `Instance`.

So the type of the expression `new ctor()` is `Instance`, but the assignment target's type annotation is (not *really*, but in some sense) a type variable `R` which could be any subtype of `Instance`, hence there is a type error.

A possible solution is to explicitly create a type variable for the return type, like so:

```
function f1<R extends Instance, T extends {new(): R}>(ctor: T) {
  const ins: R = new ctor();
  ins.print();
}
```

That said, this is only worth doing if your function deals with `R` in some other capacity, such as having a return type involving `R`. Otherwise, your code using `ins` has to work for any realisation of `R` including `Instance` itself, so you might as well declare its type as `Instance` anyway. (Likewise, if your function doesn't use `T` anywhere else, you might as well make the parameter type `Ctor` instead).

Answer (score -4):

Because you said that T extends Ctor, meaning it isn't exactly a Ctor. It could have a new that returns Instance|Instance2. Typescript has no way to know. And since Ctor declares that it always returns an Instance from it's constructor, it doesn't know the correct type to properly derive.

If you want this to work with generics and derived types, you would need to allow it to infer the derived type with a Generic parameter.

```
interface Ctor<TInstance extends Instance> {
  new(): TInstance;
}

interface Instance {
  print(): void;
}

function f1<TInstance extends Instance>(ctor: Ctor<TInstance>) {
  const ins: TInstance = new ctor();
  ins.print();
}
```

Comment: *"It could have a new that returns Instance|Instance2"* this isn't true; a type like `{new(): Instance | Instance2}` does not extend `{new(): Instance}`. If it did, you could assign a thing that constructs `Instance2` instances to something which claims to construct `Instance` instances.

Comment: Really @kaya3 ? Then why can I do this:    interface Ctor {
  new(): Instance;
}

interface Ctor2 extends Ctor {
    new(): Instance2;
}

interface Instance {
  print(): void;
}

interface Instance2 {
  print2(): void;
}

Comment: If you explicitly *declare* the type `Ctor2 extends Ctor` then of course you have a subtype; that is what `extends` means in a type declaration. But your `Ctor2` doesn't return `Instance | Instance2`, it has two overload signatures, but overload signatures are not a union type, and overload signatures are generally not typesafe in Typescript - the compiler doesn't check that you're using them correctly, it only does some sanity tests. Overload signatures are more like type assertions than types in that regard.

Comment: As for "really", yes, really, it is straightforward to confirm that `{new(): Instance | Instance2}` is not assignable to `{new(): Instance}`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgM5jiJyDeAUMsgA5ShgAUAlAFzIBuA9sACYDchAvoYZdHh50WHEgBMBYmQrhxtBi3Zde-cIMQoAwmGZQpJEBADuCtJmy4IKvgNibkOvZKKGTZkZbwAfc6KviNoRgAJ6kKAAqEFjIALyOulCSEAAekCBsGAl6yAD8yGBQAK4oDPAANhgQhAD0NcgVVYRAA)

Comment: If you are still unsure, try writing a class which implements `interface Ctor2 extends Ctor` - it needs both `print` and `print2` methods for the class itself to be assignable to `Ctor2`. Your `Ctor2` type is more like an intersection than a union, since it must construct something that is both an `Instance` and an `Instance2`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkwGcILC1Ab1QAcZwIAKASgC5UA3AexABMBuVAX1ElkQKYceFACYipcpFE16zNpx4V+yNAGEITGBLBQA7rIzZc+KIt7R4q1Bq3ioAD2hhWWG5u3FdBukeGnRc2AkABsELDcAMSYmImBUVAB6RLIKGiIeBNTpdMIeHmCmY1QkD1F6WxhxAF5UaKZ2YCA)

Comment: @kaya3 overloads are literally implimented as a type union

Comment: They aren't, and it will benefit everyone here - including yourself - if you stop making wild guesses and asserting them as facts.